# Check if image exists on SD card - Android

Tags: android, file, share

I am trying to share an image from within my app and the image is on the external storage of the device. The problem is that the user can still opt to share the image if they have manually deleted it from external storage. How do I check if they have deleted it first? Here is my share method:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void shareImage(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        //create new files
        File f = new File(mExternalImagePath);

        if (f.exists()) {
            //Do action

            f.setReadable(true, false);

            //create new file in the system
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //create new file object from the absolute path
            File f1 = f.getAbsoluteFile();
            f1.setReadable(true, false);
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(f1);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path );
            Intent mailer = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
            //mailer.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(mailer);
        }else{
            Log.d("not exist", "not exist");
        }
    }
```

It works but always shares so if the image was manually deleted, it will try sending a blank image.

Comment: `f.createNewFile();` ...Why are you creating the file if it already exists?

Comment: @FD_ My thoughts exactly. I tried to not do that and it didn't send any image. I cut it all out and did `Uri path = Uri.parse(mProfilePicPath)` was this the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: @FD_ wait...I mean mExternalImagePath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your issue is because you're creating a new file by calling `f.createNewFile()` or something else at large.

Either way, you should be able to greatly simplify your code to just get the stream and send the intent like so:

```
private void shareImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    //create new files
    File f = new File(mExternalImagePath);

    if (f.exists()) {
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(f);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        Intent mailer = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
        startActivity(mailer);
    }else{
        Log.d("not exist", "not exist");
    }
}
```

This will hopefully either clear up your issue, or make the issue more apparent and help you on your way.

You can also add a check for the file length, to ensure that it exists in some sort of readable form before you send your intent by calling `.length()` on `f`.

```
if (f.length() == 0){
    Log.d("File Empty", "File does not have any content");
}else{
    // create the intent and send
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is all in checking if it is empty. For some reason the file does still exist, but it's empty if they have manually deleted it. So I check the length is not 0 before I send, and if it is 0, it shows a dialogue explaining they have deleted the image manually.

Answer (score 3):

As @FD_ said, the createNewFile() was the problem. Be sure to add the `mailer.setType("image/*")`, so other apps can handle your sharing request.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void shareImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    File f = new File(mExternalImagePath);

    if (f.exists()) {       
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(f);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path );
        Intent mailer = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
        mailer.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(mailer);
    }else{
        Log.d("not exist", "not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Similar response to biddulph.r but I do need to also check if it's empty as the file always still exists with this code. I will set my mailer to image thanks

Comment: mailer.setType seems to cause `02-04 04:27:47.351: E/AndroidRuntime(27006): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER typ=image/* flg=0x1 (has clip) (has extras) }
02-04 04:27:47.351: E/AndroidRuntime(27006):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
`. O well. It works without it.